# TimePicker works fine on version 4 android, but in version 2.3 crash bug. (Android)

Tags: android, date, picker

I have a code that displays "TimePicker". It allows you to set the minimum and maximum value when selecting an hour from 1.15 to 11.30 and also allows you to set the interval to 15 minutes. in minutes. Code works fine on version 4 of Android, when TimePicker operates on a scroll, and on the version of android 2.3 TimePicker when displayed with the plus and minus buttons when you press one of these buttons to Exeption. Tell me what to do in the code to run on the new and old versions of android?

here's the code:

Class 1. MainActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class PickerTimeDialogProsto extends Activity {

  int DIALOG_TIME = 1;
  int myHour = 1;
  int myMinute = 15;
  TextView tvTime;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_picker_time_dialog_prosto);
        tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    }

    public void onclick(View view) {
      showDialog(DIALOG_TIME);
                }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
      if (id == DIALOG_TIME) {

        RangeTimePickerDialog tpd = new RangeTimePickerDialog(this, myCallBack, myHour, myMinute, true);

        tpd.setMin(1, 15);
        tpd.setMax(11, 30);

        return tpd;
      }
      return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }

    OnTimeSetListener myCallBack = new OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
      myHour = hourOfDay;
      myMinute = minute; 
      tvTime.setText("Time is " + myHour + " hours " + myMinute + " minutes");
    }
  };
}
```

Class 2

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

/**
 * A time dialog that allows setting a min and max time.
 * 
 */
public class RangeTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog {

    private int minHour = -1;
    private int minMinute = -1;

    private int maxHour = 25;
    private int maxMinute = 25;

    private int currentHour = 0;
    private int currentMinute = 0;

    private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    private DateFormat dateFormat;

    public RangeTimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener callBack,
            int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
        super(context, callBack, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
        currentHour = hourOfDay;
        currentMinute = minute;
        dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

        try {
            Class<?> superclass = getClass().getSuperclass();
            Field mTimePickerField = superclass.getDeclaredField("mTimePicker");
            mTimePickerField.setAccessible(true);
            TimePicker mTimePicker = (TimePicker) mTimePickerField.get(this);
            mTimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }
    }

    public void setMin(int hour, int minute) {
        minHour = hour;
        minMinute = minute;
    }

    public void setMax(int hour, int minute) {
        maxHour = hour;
        maxMinute = minute;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        boolean validTime = true;
        if (hourOfDay < minHour || (hourOfDay == minHour && minute < minMinute)) {
            validTime = false;
        }

        if (hourOfDay > maxHour || (hourOfDay == maxHour && minute > maxMinute)) {
            validTime = false;
        }

        if (validTime) {
            currentHour = hourOfDay;
            currentMinute = minute;
        }

        updateTime(currentHour, currentMinute);
        updateDialogTitle(view, currentHour, currentMinute);
    }

    private void updateDialogTitle(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay,
            int minute) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        String title = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

That's what gives Log:

```
09-06 11:34:21.802: D/dalvikvm(1213): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 104K, 48% free 2819K/5379K, external 2046K/2137K, paused 54ms
09-06 11:34:24.981: I/dalvikvm(1213): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Landroid/text/SpannableStringBuilder;.getChars:VIILI
09-06 11:34:24.981: I/dalvikvm(1213):   method requires 36+20+20=76 bytes, fp is 0x4214a334 (52 left)
09-06 11:34:24.981: I/dalvikvm(1213):   expanding stack end (0x4214a300 to 0x4214a000)
09-06 11:34:24.991: I/dalvikvm(1213): Shrank stack (to 0x4214a300, curFrame is 0x4214cebc)
09-06 11:34:24.991: D/AndroidRuntime(1213): Shutting down VM
09-06 11:34:24.991: W/dalvikvm(1213): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): java.lang.StackOverflowError
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:69)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod$ReplacementCharSequence.getChars(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:151)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:69)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.graphics.Paint.measureText(Paint.java:1068)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.text.Styled.drawUniformRun(Styled.java:146)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.text.Styled.drawDirectionalRun(Styled.java:298)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.text.Styled.measureText(Styled.java:430)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.text.Layout.measureText(Layout.java:1518)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:564)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:548)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:533)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TextView.getFocusedRect(TextView.java:4222)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:72)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:476)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:3494)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:4611)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:942)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:897)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2649)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2598)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2573)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.NumberPicker.updateView(NumberPicker.java:356)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.NumberPicker.setCurrent(NumberPicker.java:292)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.updateHourDisplay(TimePicker.java:333)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.setCurrentHour(TimePicker.java:281)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.app.TimePickerDialog.updateTime(TimePickerDialog.java:135)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at com.example.pickerdialog.RangeTimePickerDialog.onTimeChanged(RangeTimePickerDialog.java:75)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.onTimeChanged(TimePicker.java:352)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.updateHourDisplay(TimePicker.java:336)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.setCurrentHour(TimePicker.java:281)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.app.TimePickerDialog.updateTime(TimePickerDialog.java:135)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at com.example.pickerdialog.RangeTimePickerDialog.onTimeChanged(RangeTimePickerDialog.java:75)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.onTimeChanged(TimePicker.java:352)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.updateHourDisplay(TimePicker.java:336)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.setCurrentHour(TimePicker.java:281)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.app.TimePickerDialog.updateTime(TimePickerDialog.java:135)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at com.example.pickerdialog.RangeTimePickerDialog.onTimeChanged(RangeTimePickerDialog.java:75)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.onTimeChanged(TimePicker.java:352)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.updateHourDisplay(TimePicker.java:336)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.setCurrentHour(TimePicker.java:281)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.app.TimePickerDialog.updateTime(TimePickerDialog.java:135)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at com.example.pickerdialog.RangeTimePickerDialog.onTimeChanged(RangeTimePickerDialog.java:75)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.onTimeChanged(TimePicker.java:352)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.updateHourDisplay(TimePicker.java:336)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.setCurrentHour(TimePicker.java:281)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.app.TimePickerDialog.updateTime(TimePickerDialog.java:135)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at com.example.pickerdialog.RangeTimePickerDialog.onTimeChanged(RangeTimePickerDialog.java:75)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.onTimeChanged(TimePicker.java:352)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.updateHourDisplay(TimePicker.java:336)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.TimePicker.setCurrentHour(TimePicker.java:281)
09-06 11:34:25.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.app.Ti
09-06 11:34:29.132: I/Process(1213): Sending signal. PID: 1213 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You have infinite recursion. Your `onTimeChanged()` calls `updateTime()` on the time picker which in turn leads to another call to `onTimeChanged()`.

One way to fix it is to add a boolean flag in your class to prevent recursive calls to `updateTime()`. Something like:

```
boolean mIsOnTimeChanged;

@Override
public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
  if (!mIsOnTimeChanged) {
    mIsOnTimeChanged = true;

    // your regular onTimeChanged() here

    mIsOnTimeChanged = false;
  }
}
```